# Display a literalinclude block within a README.rst in GitHub

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, python-sphinx, docutils

**Goal**. Display a `literalinclude` block within a README.rst in GitHub.

**Problem**. I'm working on generating documentation for a Python project using Sphinx. The README.rst file has a literalinclude block (documentation [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude)). The literalinclude block is displayed correctly in Sphinx documentation but not in the home page of the repo in GitHub.

**Tested workarounds**. The explanation could be that the literalinclude directive is understood by Sphinx, but not by Docutils (and therefore GitHub?) as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77172274/error-using-literalinclude-with-sphinx-in-rst), which includes a reproducible example. One workaround that I've explored is to use a `.. only:` block ([link](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-only)). However, once again, it works on Sphinx documentation but not on Github, so it's likely affected by the same curse of literalinclude.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe in general GitHub doesn't process includes in the web interface for security reasons.  If you want the full capabilities of converting to HTML using your toolchain, I'd recommend GitHub Pages or another static site host to host your docs.

Comment: GitHub has limited support for rendering of reStructuredText, and `literalinclude` is not one of the supported features. It is pretty much limited to the intersection of Markdown and reStructuredText.

Comment: In plain Docutils, you could use the the "include" directive with the :literal: option. This option seems, however, not to be supported by `pandoc` or text converters derived from it.